# filter() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use jQuery to add a CSS class to an element based on the content of the element.

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr><td>apple</td></tr>
    <tr><td>banana</td></tr>
    <tr><td>pear</td></tr>
    <tr><td>watermellon</td></tr>
</table>
```

```js
$("td").filter(function() {
    $(this).text() === "pear";
}).addClass("warning");
```

I don't want to use the `:contains()` selector because I want to match exact text.  Any idea why this isn't working?  I created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bzLbu73a/

Comment: You need to return the value.. return $(this).text() === "pear";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From jQuery documentation for [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

> For each element, if the function returns true (or a "truthy" value), the element will be included in the filtered set; otherwise, it will be excluded.

All of the elements are being excluded because you aren't returning anything. Therefore you need to return the boolean so that the element will be included in the filtered set.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/6gyqthog/)

```
$("#myTable td").filter(function () {
  return $(this).text() === "1";
}).addClass("warning");
```

---

**Without jQuery:**

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/3xLc8trm/) - using [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td'), function (el) {
  if (el.textContent === '1') {
    el.classList.add('warning');
  }
});
```

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/cwnptkzz/) - using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td');
var filteredElements = Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function (el) {
  return el.textContent === '1';
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(filteredElements, function (el) {
  el.classList.add('warning');
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  It's seems obvious now that I wasn't returning Boolean.